# Mvc Contrib Grid Editing by using a Modal Popup Extender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modalpopupextender

In ASP.MVC i am able to display some data in a MvcContrb grid and have Edit and Delete Options. When i click on Delete the selected row will be deleted and the grid will be refreshed. Now when i click on Edit the user will be navigated to a new page with the Emp ID selected [Ex](http://localhost:4865/Home/UpdateEmployee?EmpId=6)

I am thinking if I can open a Modal Popup Extender with the Emp ID and display the info when we click on edit link?

Any ideas how to proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to add the AjaxControlToolkit pretty manually to use it with MVC.

I'd start here first:
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/22/asp-net-mvc-tip-36-create-a-popup-calendar-helper.aspx

Comment: I am able to replicate the calender popup successfully nad thanks for the link. I enjoyed stephen blogs. I am trying to make a modal popup extender i will let you know if i have any problems. Thanks a lot. Once i am done wth creating the modal extender i will mark the answered closed. Thanks a lot - Aditya Marla